# Scala find missing values in a range

Tags: scala, scala-collections

For a given range, for instance

```
val range = (1 to 5).toArray
val ready = Array(2,4)
```

the missing values (not *ready*) are

```
val missing = range.toSet diff ready.toSet
Set(5, 1, 3)
```

The real use case includes thousands of range instances with (possibly) thousands of *missing* or not *ready* values. Is there a more time-efficient approach in Scala?

Comment: sorting would be better option before comparing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `diff` operation is implemented in Scala as a `foldLeft` over the left operand where each element of the right operand is removed from the left collection. Let's assume that the left and right operand have `m` and `n` elements, respectively.

Calling `toSet` on an `Array` or `Range` object will return a `HashTrieSet`, which is a `HashSet` implementation and, thus, offers a remove operation with complexity of almost `O(1)`. Thus, the overall complexity for the `diff` operation is `O(m)`.

Considering now a different approach, we'll see that this is actually quite good. One could also solve the problem by sorting both ranges and then traversing them once in a merge-sort fashion to eliminate all elements which occur in both ranges. This will give you a complexity of `O(max(m, n) * log(max(m, n)))`, because you have to sort both ranges.

### Update

I ran some experiments to investigate whether you can speed up your computation by using mutable hash sets instead of immutable. The result as shown in the tables below is that it depends on the size ration of `range` and `ready`.

It seems as if using immutable hash sets is more efficient if the `ready.size/range.size < 0.2`. Above this ratio, the mutable hash sets outperform the immutable hash sets.

For my experiments, I set `range = (1 to n)`, with `n` being the number of elements in `range`. For `ready` I selected a random sub set of `range` with the respective number of elements. I repeated each run 20 times and summed up the times calculated with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

```
range.size == 100000
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| Fraction  | Immutable | Mutable |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| 0.01      |        28 |     111 |
| 0.02      |        23 |     124 |
| 0.05      |        39 |     115 |
| 0.1       |       113 |     129 |
| 0.2       |       174 |     140 |
| 0.5       |       472 |     200 |
| 0.75      |       722 |     203 |
| 0.9       |       786 |     202 |
| 1.0       |       743 |     212 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+

range.size == 500000
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| Fraction  | Immutable | Mutable |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| 0.01      |        73 |     717 |
| 0.02      |       140 |     771 |
| 0.05      |       328 |     722 |
| 0.1       |       538 |     706 |
| 0.2       |      1053 |     836 |
| 0.5       |      2543 |    1149 |
| 0.75      |      3539 |    1260 |
| 0.9       |      4171 |    1305 |
| 1.0       |      4403 |    1522 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```